# c++ release fence with atomic acquire operation example

Tags: c++, atomic

I'm looking for a example on synchronization regarding a release fence and a atomic acquire operation. All release fence examples i have found are fence-fence synchronization.

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242) mentions the fantastic **C++ Concurrency In Action**, which would explain important fence details that may not be obvious in a simple code example.

Comment: and yet, a example is needed to be sure of the understanding. and that book only had release fance - acquire fence. i found no release fence - acquire operation example. and since my processor won't generate any asserts i have no way of knowing if i learned things right or not unless i'm given a proper example

Comment: If I understand this question, you have seen synchronization examples using acquire/release semantics, but you are specifically looking for an example that uses a `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release)` with the store and a `std::atomic<T>::load(std::memory_order_acquire)` for the load?

Comment: yes. that would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

It is straightforward.. You can use a release fence and an acquire operation together like this:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    std::atomic<bool> flag{false};

    std::thread t1{[&]
    {
        x = 42;
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
        flag.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }};

    std::thread t2{[&]
    {
        if (flag.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
        {
            assert(x == 42); // cannot fire
        }
    }};

    t1.join(); t2.join();
}
```

Note that the relaxed store must be sequenced *after* the release fence.

Comment: thank you. this clears it up because someone on cppreference got confused about it and even made this revision : 
https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence&oldid=119464
so i had to be sure.